# Image source seems to be correct but I get 404

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript

simple code is written.

```
<header>
    <div>
        <img src="../../images/bonjour_logo.png" alt="">
    </div>
</header>
```

I'm just trying to get this image into my header and I'm getting this error: **Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)**

I'm pretty sure my path is correct, but maybe I'm wrong.

[image]

Comment: Use an absolute path in `src=""` instead of a page-relative href (i.e. **don't** use `../` in hardcoded URIs in Angular projects). The `src=""` path should be absolute from the _published_ site root (i.e. your `dist` folder), so if `src/app/images` is published to `https://example.com/images` then it should be `src="/images/bonjour_logo.png"`.

Comment: Remember that relative paths are relative to the URL of the PAGE that was requested, not necessarily to the file that has the reference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to load assets like images, fonts, etc.
Use angular's pre-generated assets folder, it can be found under src/assets

You can move your image to `src/assets/images/img.png` and then use the image tag as given below.

```html
<img src="assets/images/img.png" alt="image text">
```

It should work fine.

Comment: This won't work if the page's HTML is loaded under a URI that's a subdirectory path as the browser will treat this as a page-relative URI. Use `"/assets/images/img.png"` instead of `"assets/images/img.png"` and it should always work.

Answer (score 0):

You can put images folder into the folder when your html located and make src attribute like this `src="images/bonjour_logo.png"` if that doesn't work your image corrupted or server is lagging